# Can't replicate simple akka project in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, akka

I am a new `scala` user and am having problems getting a development environment functional.

I downloaded the typesafe activator which launches an editor in a web browser and was able to run the akka actor tutorial script fine.

However, I have set up my `intelliJ scala/akka` environment, and when copying the same sample code to intelliJ, I am getting compile errors. I have added akka `2.2-M1` via maven to my project.

Initially when I copy

> import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props, Actor, Inbox}

the last "Inbox" library is highlighted in red, and on compile I get "`Error: object Inbox is not a member of package akka.actor`. It suggests that I add `akka.actor.dsl.Inbox`. When I do that the import is greyed out because it is "not implimented", and get a compile error further down in the script when I go to implement inbox. It says "

```
not found: value Inbox
val inbox = Inbox.create(system)
```

"

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use sbt and then use the gen-idea plugin to create your intellij project.
You'll need to re-run gen-idea every time your dependencies change - intelliJ currently won't automatically discover and resolve managed dependencies for you.

here is the plugin with directions.
https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea

also, as a professional I would recommend you use the sbt console for most of your tasks.
Ctrl-tab 0 will let you hop over there without touching your mouse.
Escape brings you back to the code editor window.
You can run sbt ~test to test on change to your files etc.

Note you may need to change focus off of intellij for it to save the file in memory if you're use ~test

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve the same issue by adding the following library from the Maven repository

`com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.2-M3`

to File -- Project Structure -- Libraries